# Amadeus API - What is the page[limit] parameter?

Tags: python, amadeus

I am trying to use the point of interest API from Amadeus in Python

```
from amadeus import Client, ResponseError

amadeus = Client(
    client_id='<my_client_id>',
    client_secret='<my_client_secret>'
)

response = amadeus.reference_data.locations.points_of_interest.by_square.get(
    north=41.42,
    west=2.11,
    south=41.347463,
    east=2.228208,
    categories = ['SIGHTS','NIGHTLIFE'],
    <page_limit?> = 5
)
```

According to the [documentation](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/destination-experiences/api-doc/points-of-interest/api-reference), there is one parameter called page[limit] which its default is 10. But I am not able to get the name of that parameter that should be used in the Python method above. Does anyone know what is the name of the parameter?

I have tried using `page[limit]` as a parameter but I get an error. I also tried with `page_limit` but the method just ignores this parameter.

Comment: something like `page = { offset: 1, limit: 2 }`

Comment: You are right, thanks! This worked for me:
page = { 'offset': 1, 'limit': 5 }

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
page = { 'offset': 1, 'limit': 5 }
```

Thank you [Iłya Bursov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864275/i%C5%82ya-bursov)